# How to Update Value at Column A from Value at Column B in JavaFX TableView?

Tags: javafx

I have two columns:

```
TableColumn<class, DatePicker> colCurrentDate;
TableColumn<class, String> colDateAfter3Days;
```

I want to update value shown in `colDateAfter3Days` as soon as I change the date in `colCurrentDate`.

I tried to use `setOnCommit()` on the `colCurrentDate` column but it is never called.

Comment: Can you show more code? Your model class and the cell value factories that you have?

Comment: Could you also post code that does not fail to compile since you're trying to use java keywords as identifiers. Furthermore if the second column should simply contain the value of the first column + 3 days you should probably simply use a binding that depends on the property used for the first column...

Comment: @fabian can you please tell me that which java keywords i might have used as identifier because as far as i know i have not used any. I have also tried to use binding but it is not working. Although I have found one solution but it needs to update table whenever i update colCurrentDate.